# Hibernate : fetch lazy collection with HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have two large tables (> 100 million rows each), let's call them Parent and Child (Parent with a lazy one to many relation to Child). The query is very slow when I use a join fetch 
and I also get a hibernate warning "HH000104 firstresult maxresults specified with collection fetch applying in memory" because I use a limit.

So I am trying to get the data in two separated queries:
- first query gets all parents with a limit
- second query gets children with parent.id in the parent ids found by the first query

This solution performs very well, however hibernate does not aggregate the children with their parents, although the two queries are executed in the same session.

I wonder if there is a way to achieve this using HQL or some java code:
- I do not wish to use the criteria API (I would need to rewrite many queries and I find criteria API queries hard to maintain)
- I do not want to change the Parent/Child relation to EAGER/BATCH because I would not be able to query the Parent without the Child

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

The second query should not get children only: Hibernate would have no way to know that all the children of each parent has been fetched.

The second query should get the parents with their children (but using an `in` clause selecting only the desired parents, and without limit):

First query, with a limit applied:

```
select distinct p.id from Parent p where ...
```

Second query, with no limit applied:

```
select p from Parent p left join fetch p.children where p.id in :idsSelectedByTheFirstQuery
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. With this solution, the second query performs poorly. Because the children have the parent id I am hoping I can load them in separated queries and group them in the session…

Comment: Why does it perform poorly? It shouldn't perform significantly more poorly than the query selecting the children only, unless you don't have an index on the join column between child and parent. Now, if only you posted your code and your DDL, we wouldn't have to guess everything.

Comment: The performance issue only happens when the tables have millions of rows, so one would also need the database to reproduce it.
I am hoping that there is a 'simple' solution for assembling the beans that do not require having the classes nor the code ...
I use postgresql and I was not able to find out what goes wrong with the query from the execution plan when fetching both parent and children. Of course there is an index between parent and child tables.
My guess is the query returns more data as every parent has at least two children, so fetching both means returning each parent twice …

Comment: @JDM there should be no reason it perform significantly slower than what you are proposing.  Your original suggestion is something like `from Child where parent.id in :idsSelectedByTheFirstQuery`.  The difference of the generated SQL is simply joining of Parent and Child table, which should be nothing even there are million records, given that you have proper index